# Show more than 3 PagerTitleStrip

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I am using a `ViewPager` in which I am able to have 3 `PagerTabStrip`. But I want to have more than 3, maybe 4 or 5. I tried using `setTextSpacing()` but that didn't work. There is no direct option also to have some a some amount of `PaperTitleStrip`.

Any Suggestions how can we implement the same.

Comment: I even tried setting -ve padding in setPadding(), that also didnt work.

Answer (score 0):

This is what javadoc says:

> PagerTabStrip is an interactive indicator of the current, next, and
>   previous pages of a ViewPager.

But if you are still in doubts see sources: `PagerTabStrip.java` and its base class `PagerTitleStrip.java` and will see:

```
public class PagerTitleStrip extends ViewGroup implements iewPager.Decor {
    private static final String TAG = "PagerTitleStrip";

    ViewPager mPager;
    TextView mPrevText;
    TextView mCurrText;
    TextView mNextText;
```

Which means: there are only three strips: prev, current and next.

Comment: This occurs for both of those classes. How do you make it look like on Lollipop's contact app, for example?